# Suppress (or quiet) the output of bash: "Hit any key to close this window..."

Tags: bash, vim, cygwin, interactive

Typically when I invoke an GUI application in vim, I get a command prompt that awaits for my response:

```
shell returned 1
Hit any key to close this window...
```

How can I not make this prompt to show up, or not require me to press a key?

```
shortmess+=A
```

does not make the message go away

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are referring to Windows' cmd.exe window, which is the only place I can find this prompt with this specific wording.

Unfortunately, you are stuck with this prompt if you want an interactive "shell" window under Windows.  However, if user interaction is not necessary or if the command you are running brings up its own window for interaction you can try this instead:

```
:!start yourcommand
```

For more information, see:

```
:help :!start
```